# cakephp library data to controller

Tags: cakephp, controller

I have a lib in app/Lib/mylibrary.php
It grabs user info from our ldap server. 
The lib function is called in the controller and working fine.

How can I pass the resulting user data from the lib function to a controller?
I know how to get a true or false, but not how to pass values to the controller.

Comment: What does your lib look like? It totally depends on what data is returned by the function that verifies the credentials.

Comment: Also always specify the cake version you are using. If you are using 2.x your file should be "Mylibrary.php" containing a class called "Mylibrary" (note the casing).

Comment: The data returned is in an array, Cake v 2.2.1. I want to be able to use the array value & keys in the controller.                                     `array(
 'count' => (int) 1,
 (int) 0 => array(
  'cn' => array(
   'count' => (int) 1,
   (int) 0 => 'name'
  ),
  (int) 0 => 'cn',
  'sn' => array(
   'count' => (int) 1,
   (int) 0 => 'surname'
  ),
  (int) 1 => 'sn',
  'c' => array(
   'count' => (int) 1,
   (int) 0 => 'US'
  ),`

Answer (score 0):

The resulting array just needed to be returned.

```
return $array;
```

Which passes it to the controller.